# In a group of order 21, every normal subgroup is cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $P$ be a group of order $21$. How to prove that   each normal subgroup of $P$ is cyclic?

Comment: I replaced the images with TeX markup. See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each  `proper` subgroup of P is cyclic, whether normal or not. Indeed the order of such a subgroup is a strict divisor of 21, by Lagrange's theorem, hence it is of order $1$, $3$ or $7$. It suffices to know a group of prime order is cyclic.